# Getting Tag from Tap Gesture Recognizer

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I've got an array of UIImageViews and have programmatically assigned tap gesture recognizers to them.

```
    myImages.forEach{ UIImageView in
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(gesture:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        }
```

What's the best way to assign a sender to each (or determine which image was tapped another way)?  I've unsuccessfully tried

```
var tag = sender.view!.tag
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

in here you need to follow two steps,

**step 1**

assign the `tags` for imageview before append to your  myImages array.

**step 2**

get  the tag from imageview array and assign to your each gesture

```
myImages.forEach{  
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tap.view?.tag =  $0.tag
        $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        $0.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
```

and handle the func like

```
  @objc func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
     guard let getTag = sender.view?.tag else { return }
    print("getTag == \(getTag)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the block provided by UITapGestureRecognizer init to access your images in place.

```
myImages.forEach { image in
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(block: {[weak self] _ in
       //Do your stuff here
       //print("Image Tapped:", image.debugDescription)
}, delegate: self)
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
image.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set **UITapGestureRecognizer** in **UICollectionView  or UITableView cell** then below solution is useful for us.

**Step 1**  Assign the UITapGestureRecognizer to particuller textview or other view in UICollectionView  or UITableView cell.

```
cell.textView?.delegate = self
cell.textView?.isEditable = false
cell.textView?.isSelectable = true
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:#selector(self.onclickLink(_:)))
cell.textView?.tag = indexPath.row
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
cell.textView?.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

**Step 2** Get the tag from UITextView or other View in onclick action.

```
    @IBAction func onclickLink(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("indexPathRow == \(sender.view?.tag ?? 0)")            
    }
```